# MS Word Export to PDF Makes Images Soft

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

We have a bunch of letterheads that we have created in MS Word for Mac.  These looks great on the mac and when we make them into a PDF they still look great.

When trying them on a PC, they still look sharp, but when saving as a PDF and viewing the image is now soft. The image has text in it and it looks horrible.

Is there a reason why MS Word would be making our images soft when saving as a PDF?

MS Word 2010
Image is a jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Office 2010, but try looking under PDF settings, see if there are image settings related to JPEGs. Many PDF compressors by default decrease the quality/resolution in order to save file size when converting to PDF. Office on your PC may be configured differently than your Mac.

If the above doesn't work, and quality is important, I'd suggest trying to save them using a virtual PDF printer such as [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/).

Comment: I am not finding any PDF settings.  Word 2010 has an Image Size and Quality setting, but I tested it and it doesn't effect anything for saving a PDF.  The images are still soft.

Comment: Yes I did, it does nothing to help.